# Regex for a range of numbers separated by commas N times

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this regex to validate VLAN input between `1 and 4096`, the numbers must be separated by commas but I don't know how to make the regex reject repeating commas and ending with a comma.

I need this:

```
1234,234,4096 (no repeating commas, no spaces, no commas at the end)
```

right now my regex is allowing this also:

```
1234,,234,4096,
```

this is my regex:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-6]))(?:[,]+(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-6]))?)*$
```

Thanks fot the help.

Comment: why `[,]+` ? if you don't want multiple `,` to be matched ?

Comment: You are right, but multiple commas where allowed by the regex even without the "+"

Comment: because this part is optional `(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-6]))?` so `(?:[,]+(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-6]))?)*` this is actually behave as `(?:[,]+)*` where there are `,,,` and it matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your regex

```
[,]+(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-6]))?
```

- `[,]+` - this will allow more than 1 `,` to match
- `(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-6]))?` - since this is optional so it will let `,,` to match

You can use this pattern

```
^(?:(?:\d{1,3}|[0-3]\d{3}|40[0-8]\d|409[0-6]),)*?(?:(?:\d{1,3}|[0-3]\d{3}|40[0-8]\d|409[0-6]))$
```

[image]

So in this regex the idea is match number followed by , zero or more time ( make it lazy so to allow the last group where we are matching a number without trailing comma ) followed by number without trailing comma

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/TXHHLD/1/)

```js
const regex = /^(?:(?:\d{1,3}|[0-3]\d{3}|40[0-8]\d|409[0-6]),)*?(?:(?:\d{1,3}|[0-3]\d{3}|40[0-8]\d|409[0-6]))$/;
const strs = ['1234,234,4096', '1234,,234,4096,', '1234', '1234,', '4097', '4096']

strs.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, '\t\t\t', regex.test(str))
})
```

---

> Edit:- although I forgot to mention that it cannot allow zeros at the
>   start.

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40[0-8]\d|409[0-6]),)*?(?:(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40[0-8]\d|409[0-6]))$
```

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/TXHHLD/2/)

Comment: thank you very much @CodeManiac, this is very helpful, although I forgot to mention that it cannot allow zeros at the start. but i will analyze your explanation. thanks again.

Comment: @DavidHume always happy to help, you can adjust the allowed digits in desired manner, see the update it will help you

Comment: I am very grateful @CodeManiac this is my first time with regex and it was driving me nuts!

Comment: @DavidHume whenever there's possibilities you can avoid regex ( when it turn out to be getting tedious ) you should avoid it, always give preference to simple code that will be easy for you as well as other people who're going to maintain or read your code in future

Comment: Actually that was the same thing I said to my boss but she just wants regex @CodeManiac

Answer (score 2):

I vote for *not* using regex here, and instead splitting the string by comma and checking each element:

```js
var input = "1234,234,4096";
var parts = input.split(",");
var success = true;
for (var i=0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(parts[i]) || parts[i] < 1 || parts[i] > 4096) {
        success = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (success) {
    console.log("CSV string is valid.");
}
else {
    console.log("CSV string is invalid");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim, I wanted to do this also, but the boss insists in using regex

Comment: The sun will freeze before that happens hahaha @Tim Biegeleisen